Beta functions for Yukawa theory
I am trying to compute the beta function for the Yukawa theory
$$L_Y = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \phi)^2+\frac{M^2}{2}\phi^2+\bar\psi(\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m)\psi-\lambda \phi^4/4!+i g\phi \bar\psi\gamma_5\psi$$ (where $\phi$ is a pseudocscalar, to keep the action real, this theory has $Z_2$ symmetry).
I am sticking to Srednicky QFT book, chapter 28. I arrived to an equation which is the generalization for the Yukawa coupling, of eq. 28.19 in Srednicky which is:
$$(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\epsilon^n} \tilde G_n(\lambda,g))k\frac{\partial g}{\partial k}+g\epsilon+g\frac{\partial }{\partial \lambda}(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\epsilon ^n}\tilde G_n(\lambda, g))k\frac{d\lambda}{dk} =0 $$
here I am sticking to the $\bar{MS}$ scheme and to make my eq. and Srednicky's match we have to identify $ln(\mu)=k$.
My problem is with equation 28.20:
Srednicky says: "since $k\frac{d}{dk} g$ is the rate at which the coupling constant changes to compensate in a small change of the scale k, for a renormalizable theory We expect this rate to be finite", this is why he is able to write equation 28.20; following my lecture notes the corresponding equation in this case must be:
$$k\frac{\partial}{\partial k}g = \beta_g(g,\lambda)-g\epsilon $$
In order to arrive to this last eq. I have to match terms of various orders in $\epsilon$, but I am a bit confused with which other equation I have to match things.
Can someone help me out in trying to understand the sense of it? Thank you all in advance!
(PS: i have all the 1 loop results for divergent diagrams to compute everything; at 1 loop $\tilde G_n(\lambda, g)$ does not depend on $\lambda$).
